# What is the meaning of the perfect participle clause 'anyone having touched this wire...'

Tags: phrase-meaning, participles

1. Anyone **touching** this wire will get a shock.

I know here the participle clause means '*anyone **who touches** this wire..*'. 
My question is, if I'd use perfect participles(*having touched*)  instead of *touching*, 
like,

2. Anyone **having touched** this wire will get a shock.

what does here *having touched* mean?
( Does it mean like,'Anyone **who has touched** this wire.. or **After** anyone has touched this wire he(she) will get a shock.?)

Answer (score 3):

RULE OF THUMB: Use the perfect only if the sense may be paraphrased as a relative clause with a perfect in the tense corresponding to the Reference Time (RT) of your sentence:

> NON-PAST RT
> <sup>∗</sup> Anyone having touched this wire <sup>NonPast</sup>will get a shock =
> <sup>∗</sup> Anyone who <sup>NonPast</sup>has touched this wire <sup>NonPast</sup>will get a shock.
>
> PAST RT
> <sup>∗</sup> Anyone having touched this wire <sup>Past</sup>would get a shock =
> <sup>∗</sup> Anyone who <sup>Past</sup>had touched this wire <sup>Past</sup>would get a shock.

You should not use a perfect here, because that names an event happening at any time  before getting the shock; it would imply, for instance, that if I touched the wire yesterday I will get a shock today or tomorrow!

But in these cases the perfect is acceptable, because the prior purchase might have occurred at any time prior to the refund:

> NON-PAST RT
> <sup>ok</sup>Anyone having bought this item <sup>NonPast</sup>can get a refund=
> <sup>ok</sup>Anyone who <sup>NonPast</sup>has bought this item <sup>NonPast</sup>can get a refund.
>
> PAST RT
> <sup>ok</sup>Anyone having bought this item <sup>Past</sup>could get a refund =
> <sup>ok</sup>Anyone who <sup>Past</sup>had bought this item <sup>Past</sup>could get a refund.

Comment: Doesn't the sentence "Anyone having bought this item can get a refund" mean a sense like, 'after having bought this item anyone can get a refund"

Comment: @Dinusha No; that sense would be expressed by *Anyone buying...* OR  *Anyone, having bought...,*. Participial perfects are tricky; avoid them unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: you mean that commas must be used after the subject (with perfect participle), to mean "_after having bought this item anyone can..._"?

Comment: @Dinusha Yes. The participle clause has to modify the head clause, not its subject.

Comment: as you say in the answer , "Anyone having bought this item..." is equal to "Anyone who has(had) bought this item..." it means  _anyone_ is modified by 'having bought'. therefore, is it possible to use in this way like,'Do you know **anyone having bought this item**'?

Comment: @Dinusha That's grammatical; but the relative clause is the more usual way of expressing it. Leave the participial perfects to lawyers and bureaucrats.

Comment: Using perfect participle to modify nouns doesn't often use? or is it awkward?

Comment: @Dinusha This use is fairly rare and takes extra 'processing' by the reader. That's why it's used mostly in the language of laws and contracts, where the writers don't care whether or not it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

First of all that sentence (Anyone having touched this wire will get a shock.) sounds a bit ungrammatical to me. (I am not sure if this sentence formation is correct or not) So for me it doesn't mean anything.  Because this sentence doesn't fit in either past perfect tense or in future tense.

Let's take few examples here

1. Having got tired from work i turned their offer down to go for a movie.
2. Having driven my car for two hours I decided to stop by to take some rest.

Here 'having got tired' means - because i got tired i turned their offer down to go for a movie.

Here 'having driven' means - after i drove my car for two hours I decided to take some rest.

So 'having + verb' can either mean after / because as per the situation.

So your example - (Anyone having touched this wire will get a shock.) It doesn't clarify whether the action has been done or it will be done in future. If it is to be done in future then the sentence would be

1. Anyone who touches this wire will get a shock. (Action will happen)
2. Anyone will get a shock when he or she touches this wire.

Or when the action has been completed then

3. Whoever touched this wire got a shock. (Action completed)
4. Having touched this wire he got a shock. (He got a shock after he touched the wire)